# How install WP-CLI for wordpress under wamp sever

Tags: wordpress, windows, ssh, wamp, wp-cli

Cannot figure this out?

How do I install WP-CLI for wordpress under wamp sever also how to enter the ssh shell comandline under wampserver?

https://wp-cli.org/
ssh wampserver
command line interface
Try do install

https://wp-cli.org/
ssh wampserver
command line interface
Try do install